# GuiControl works with one variable but not another

Tags: autohotkey

I am at my wit's end trying to figure out what's wrong with my program.

It's an AutoHotkey v1.1.19.02 script designed to do the following: When you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, read a file from disk into the clipboard and then paste it into a text field. It has a simple GUI with a drop-down list to select which file should be read. It also has a checkbox which, when selected, will advance to the next file every time the hotkey is pressed.

So you should be able to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> over and over again, and the script will paste in one file at a time. The dropdown list informs you which file is next and lets you pick a different one if you like.

I have the functionality for reading the file and pasting it in, but I can't get the dropdown list to update based on which file is selected. Here's my script:

```
SendMode Play
SetWorkingDir, C:\files

global FileIndex
global AutoAdvance = 1
global File1 := "folder 1\file1.html"
global File2 := "folder 1\file2.html"
global File3 := "folder 1\file3.html"
global File4 := "folder 2\file1.html"
global File5 := "folder 2\file2.html"
global File6 := "folder 2\file3.html"
; etc

Gui, New
Gui, Add, DropDownList, vFileDropdown gGuiSubmit w250 AltSubmit HwndFileDropdownHwnd
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vAutoAdvance gGuiSubmit checked, Auto-advance
Loop, 6
{
    GuiControl, , FileDropdown, % File%A_Index%
    ;TrayTip, PortalPaste, %A_LoopFileName%
}
GuiControl, Choose, FileDropdown, %File1%
Gui, Show,, PortalPaste

GuiSubmit:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    FileIndex := FileDropdown
    Gosub, GuiUpdate
    ;TrayTip, PortalPaste, Auto-advance: %AutoAdvance%. FileIndex: %FileIndex%. File name: %FileName%
return

#q::
GuiUpdate:
    FileN := File%FileIndex%
    TrayTip, PortalPaste, File5: %File5%`nFileN: %FileN%
    GuiControl, ChooseString, ComboBox1, %FileN%
return

TrayTip, PortalPaste, Assistant ready. File dir: %A_WorkingDir%

>!r::Reload
>!e::Edit

#v::
    Send, ^a ; select all
    FileName := File%FileIndex%
    FileRead, Clipboard, %FileName%
    Send, ^v
    if (AutoAdvance) {
        FileIndex++
    }
    Gosub, GuiUpdate
return
```

I've isolated the problem to the GuiUpdate subroutine:

```
GuiUpdate:
    FileN := File%FileIndex%
    TrayTip, PortalPaste, File5: %File5%`nFileN: %FileN%
    GuiControl, ChooseString, ComboBox1, %FileN% ; this line is the problem
return
```

I've used `TrayTip` to verify that my variables have the values I intend at that point. If I edit that line to refer to `%File5%` instead of `%FileN%`, `GuiControl` will set the ComboBox to entry #5. But as long as I have `%FileN%` on that line, `GuiControl` does nothing--even when the variables `FileN` and `File5` have identical contents!

I even put these lines into `GuiUpdate:` to verify that the variables are equal.

```
truth := FileN == File5
TrayTip, PortalPaste, File5: %File5%`nFileN: %FileN%`nThe two are equal: %truth%
```

When `FileIndex` is 5, `truth` evaluates to 1 in the tooltip. How can `GuiControl, ChooseString, ComboBox1, %File5%` work and       `GuiControl, ChooseString, ComboBox1, %FileN%` not, when `File5 == FileN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MJs of the AHKscript.org forums [answered my question](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6307&p=37434#p37320). `GuiControl` wasn't targeting the right control because I created the window with `Gui, New`. Removing `Gui, New` fixed the problem.